# how i can add validator: (value) { if (value.isEmpty) { return 'Please enter some text'; } return null; }, );

Tags: validation, flutter, textfield

```
import 'package:awwapp/Auth/registration.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// import 'package:flutter/services.dart';


class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
   TextStyle style = TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat', fontSize: 20.0);

   final  _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override


  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

      final emailField = TextField(

          obscureText: false,
          style: style,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
              hintText: "Email",
              border:
                  OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0))),

        );
        final passwordField = TextField(
          obscureText: true,
          style: style,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
              hintText: "Password",
              border:
                  OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0))),
        );

        final loginButon = Material(
          elevation: 5.0,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
          color: Color(0xff01A0C7),
          child: MaterialButton(
            minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text("Login",
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: style.copyWith(
                    color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          ),
        );

         final registrationButton = Material(
          elevation: 5.0,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
          color: Color(0xff01A0C7),
          child: MaterialButton(
            minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
            onPressed: () {
               Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => RegistrationPage()),
                      );
            },
            child: Text("Register",
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: style.copyWith(
                    color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          ),
        );



    return Scaffold(
       body: Form(
         key: _formKey,
              child: Center(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.white,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(36.0),

                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 155.0,
                        child: Image.asset(
                          "assets/logo/logo.png",
                          fit: BoxFit.contain,
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 45.0),
                      emailField,
                      SizedBox(height: 25.0),
                      passwordField,
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 35.0,
                      ),
                      loginButon,
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 15.0,
                      ),
                      registrationButton,
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
       ),



    );
  }
}





"TextFormField(
  // The validator receives the text that the user has entered.
  validator: (value) {
    if (value.isEmpty) {
      return 'Please enter some text';
    }
    return null;
  },
); "
```

here is the my whole code 
i am creating login for my project and i want to validate these fields that is mention at above and i want to add code that i mentioned in double qoutes how i can add these code in my above mention code
i Want to validate these fields but i am facing errors plz help me how can i add
how i can add code mention in double quotes in my above code

Answer (score 0):

You already have a form. What you need to change the TextField to TextFormField. 
TextFormField supports the validator method.

See the complete sample at bottom of this link
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/validation